# How can you make meshes transparant in sculptmode?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

[image]

I am trying to create a relief using an image as reference. The way i would like to do this would require to make the mesh transparent in sculptmode, but i can´t find this option. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ***Cycles*** add a material to your plane and set up material nodes as pictured below (Mix *Diffuse* and *Transparent* nodes). With the viewport shading type set to ***Material*** set the *Factor* of the *Mix* node to adjust transparency as you like. In *Material* header-->*Settings* panel under the *Viewport Color* set the *Alpha* to 0.000.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Wow, that´s exactly what i was looking for, thanks!